# Teams section should validate question and then ask if I want to post publicly

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams

If you flip from your team to public to ask a question and don't enter any information in the title or body the and click the `post your public question` button then the system warns if you really want to post the question publicly.

Should it not first verify and validate the fields before asking me?  I would think it would need to validate my controls and ensure i have good content and only then ask me.

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiousity. What happens if you click yes?

Comment: @AndréKool the validation kicks in after that. It's like clicking the submit button a second time.

Comment: I believe this is no longer an issue, with the shift of Teams to its own separate domain; there's no option to switch which site to ask the question on. As such, I'm closing this question as no longer reproducible.